# Using Auto Layout in Interface Builder with complex views

Tags: ios, iphone, user-interface, interface-builder, autolayout

So, here's a tricky one. I'm working on a portrait only app that should be compatible with the iPhone 4s, 5/5s/5c and 6/6 Plus. Unfortunately, I'm having some troubles working with Auto Layout in order to make the user interface fully compatible with the previous listed devices.

Here's a screenshot of how the UI should look like (this is from an iPhone 6 Plus that I'm using as a reference for the other screen sizes):

[image]

I have a 338x338 points blueCircle, a 180x180 redCircle, a 118x118 greenCircle, a 84x84 purpleCircle and, finally, a 50 points tall adBanner. The result I would like to achieve is to have an iPhone 6 Plus UI that respects these view sizes and a properly shrunk down UI for all the other ones; in addition to that I will let the users pay to remove the advertisement banner on the bottom so I need to resize the UI accordingly too (set circles vertical spacing to the banner and set its height to 0 maybe?). I messed around with Interface Builder and I came out with a decent - not so precise - result. Take a look at the UI on an iPhone 4s screen:

[image]

It looks decent but there's major problem. In Interface Builder I'm working on a Freeform ViewController with the same width of an iPhone 6 Plus (414 points) on which I've added all those circle views with the previously listed frame sizes. To make an example, let's temporarily ignore all the other constraints to concentrate on the aspect ratio ones: on the 338x338 blueCircle I've added an aspect ratio constraint, the same on the 180x180 redCircle. Then I've control-dragged from the redCircle to the blueCircle and clicked again on aspect ratio so that it resizes accordingly to the blueCircle. As I said the result wasn't precise since, if I println() redCircle's frame, the console will say that its width equals to 175.666666666667 (instead of 180) points.

[Here's](http://cl.ly/1U091Y2J2Z0q) the project so you can check it out yourself. I believe its worth more than a thousand words. I'm not very good at Auto Layout and I'm sure I'm creating too many useless constraints. What could I do to improve my layout?

Comment: Does it HAVE to be auto-layout? Things like that seem to be much easier when laid out through code .. but maybe that's just my opinion. - I'm also not very familiar with auto-layout, sadly.

Comment: I think you're going to need a bit more logic than auto-layout allows in IB. I would work out what the simplest constraints you could use are and then adjust them in code when the view is loaded.

It's possible to have a reference to a constraint in your code, just as you can with views themselves (control-drag to your code). I've done this to finesse some constraints to get things just right.

For example, if you're not happy with a width turning out to be 175.66667, then in code you could adjust the constraint after doing some rounding.

Comment: Currently I'm not using Auto Layout in my actual project. I just check the view frame to see on which device the app is running. I had some problems with this approach when the interface changes its height when the status bar height increases because of a background call/navigation/audio.

Comment: It looks like autolayout is working exactly as it should. The whole point of autolayout is to stop thinking about designs in terms of specific pixels. Does it actually matter functionally that the red circle isn't exactly 180 points?

Answer (score 0):

you need to set height and width of all the circle views as proportional to its parent view.
I set the height of blue view as 0.5 proportional to its parent view and its width will be in aspect ration with itself as 1:1
repeat same for all the other views and apply vertical spacing and horizontal spacing as required between views

this is how it looks on iphone 4

[image]

this is how it looks on iphone 6 plus

[image]